# change columns from their current varchar datatype to date and datetime datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi Guys I still have not got answer to this problem. I have 100 colums in a table which are varchar datatype. I want to change them from varchar datatype to datedatatype. these colums are datefield colums say [Vax hover delivery actual date]. so how can I change them from their current varchar datatype to date and datetime datatype. I will appreciate. thanks

Comment: I dont understand complitely what you want, but may be  SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, dateFeild1, 120), CONVERT(Datetime, dateFeild2, 120),... from YOUR_TABLE helps you?

Comment: If it's a one-time deal, consider a multistep approach: create a copy of your table, truncate it, change the column definitions,  import/insert data from the original, drop the original, rename the copy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert your current column values in a temp table.
2. Drop column from table.
3. Recreate a column on table with date type with nullablity.
4. Update new column on table with values in the temp table.

Comment: can you help with example please. lets say my table is named MyTableuwbe with 40 columns and I want to change 10 column from varchar to date. How will I apply your logic. thanks

Comment: does your problem is about converting varchar to date?